# How can I work write with dates in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter

I have a task for working with dates. The meaning of a task is to create a date in ISO format. I can do this:

```
var date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
```

Well, the result of function is 2018-02-25T15:51:51+03:00

How can I output the beginning of a next day in this format?

I tried to deal with dataComponents but I failed.
I am a beginner in Swift 4 development and I need your help, please.

Comment: Please only ask one question per post.

Comment: "Z" as the timezone means the Zulu (UTC or GMT+0) timezone. But you are specifying the user's current timezone.

Comment: Just combine the duplicated questions to achieve what you want